# Prove $xy^2-e^{-y}-1=0$ is an implicit solution of the differential equation $(xy^2+2xy-1)y'+y^2=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Prove $xy^2-e^{-y}-1=0$ is an implicit solution of the differential equation $(xy^2+2xy-1)y'+y^2=0$.

I try to implicitly differentiate this equation and it gives $2xyy'+y^2+e^{-y}y'=0$. This doesn't look like the original equation. Is there something wrong with my answer? How do you prove this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original equation of $xy^2-e^{-y}-1=0$ can be rearranged to be

$$e^{-y} = xy^2 - 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Substituting this into your implicitly differentiated equation (which appears to me to be correct) of

$$2xyy'+y^2+e^{-y}y'=0 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

gives

$$2xyy' + y^2 + (xy^2 - 1)y' = 0 \; \iff \; (xy^2 + 2xy - 1)y' + y^2 = 0 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

where the terms with the common factor of $y'$ are grouped together on the right. This is the same as what you're asked to prove.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your differentiation of the equation
$$xy^2-e^{-y}-1=0\,\Rightarrow\,y^2+2xyy'+e^{-y}y'=0$$
which can we re-written as:
$$y'\left(2xy+e^{-y}\right)+y^2=0$$
since the whole equation (or even the inside of the brackets) is out by a non-constant and instead a function, I would presume what one of these equations are wrong?

Comment: Now you just replace the remaining $e^{-y}$ using the implicit solution equation. This then replicates all the steps of the other answer. One could also have started with $y=-\ln(xy^2-1)$ and transform its derivative to a fraction-free form.